# How to use real escape string in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, pdo, eloquent, laravel-5

is there any built-in way or method available to implement `mysqli_real_escape_string` method. I have some custom data on which I have to implement this method.

I tried this `\DB::escape()` method in laravel but got following error.

> **ErrorException in DatabaseManager.php line 296: call_user_func_array()**
>
> expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class
>   'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'escape'

while If I try manually implement this method `mysqli_real_escape_string` got following error.

> **ErrorException in Contact.php line 348: mysqli_real_escape_string()**
>   expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

I did some R&D, for this method `mysqli_real_escape_string()` I have to pass 2 parameter 1 is DB connection link, and 2nd is string to implement method action. but now, How I will know Laravel DB connection link?

any idea or solution for this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), so there's no escaping, just prepared statements. See the [Laravel manual on databases](http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw).

If you absolutely need this type of feature, you could try `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote()` instead.

Comment: The quote method is what i needed. Its difficult zu browse Laravel framework although i´m using PHPStorm.